# Excel COUNTIF issue

Tags: excel

I am trying to count the number of values present by referencing another column. Example:

```
Reference table
Person 1
Person 2
Person 3
Person 4
Person 5


Tables w/Values
Person 1    X   
Person 1    X   
Person 1    X   X
Person 1    X   X
Person 1        X
Person 1    X   X
Person 2    x   
Person 2    x   
Person 2        x
Person 2        x
```

The result I want here would be

```
Person 1 9
Person 2 4
```

However, I want this populated in a formula so that I can calculate a percentage against that specific person

Comment: Can you not use two `Countifs` formulas, and just add them together? Are the `X` values in two columns, I assume?

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is more clear now.

Try this:

=COUNTIF($B$7:$B$37,A3)/(COUNTA($B$7:$B$37))

Assuming that your reference table starts in A3 and your table with values starts in B7 and ends in B37

Your result will be the count of the values given the Person indicated in your reference table.